# How can I load an a-frame's a-image that doesn't have a 1:1 size ratio

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe

I am trying to learn A-frame and have been playing around with different entities. The static objects are able to load(box, cylinder, etc) but some things with a src attribute don't work.

I have looked online and in the docs but can't find any clear help.

I was able to get the 1:1 image load that was (512X512) in size. Though now when I try to have an image with varying widths and heights it rejects the image.

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.0/aframe.min.js"></script>

<body>
 <a-scene>
   <a-assets>
  <img id="boxTexture" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519575706483-221027bfbb31?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80">
   </a-assets>

   <a-image src="#boxTexture" position="0 1.5 -1" rotation="0 0 0" crossOrigin="anonymous"></a-image>

   <a-sky color="#222"></a-sky>
 </a-scene>
</body>
```

I thought it was going to show me the image I linked to as it did with the 1:1 image but it just showed a black square. Looking at the console I see this error which didn't show on the 1:1 image.

THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture has been resized from (1000x667) to (512x512).
s @ three.js:20075

The other thing that stuck out to me was this warning.

three.js:19907 THREE.WebGLState: DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': Tainted canvases may not be loaded.

Why does it need to try and make it (512x512) and is there a way I can make is make an image of a different size.

Comment: Which browser are you using for this? I can see the image being rendered in above code snippet. Though the image resize warning is still there.

Comment: I am using google chrome which after googling might be the issues due to the crossorigin header. I tried adding the crossorigin="anonymous" tag but it still didnt work. Thank you for suggesting to look into the browser itself as Firefox was able to load the images.

Comment: I also learned that some URLs cant be accessed outside of their domain so that also was one of the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message you saw is just a warning and the experience should still render. Ideally textures dimensions should be [power of two](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26187/why-are-textures-always-square-powers-of-two-what-if-they-arent) but don't have to be square: 1024x512, 512x2048 are valid sizes. Look at the following A-Frame example that uses images of different sizes:

https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/showcase/shopping/

https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/examples/showcase/shopping/index.html

Make also sure that the server you fetch the images has [CORS headers setup](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/core/asset-management-system.html#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors)